# Building a Custom Flash Video Player using JavaScript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen lot of articles for how to play videos of types (.mp4, .ogg etc) using JavaScript, HTML with full controls like play, replay, mute/unmute volume, progress bar, But no any article i found for how to play flash video(.swf) with full controls of same as others type of videos. Anyone did this ??

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks..

Comment: That's because you need Flash to play Flash videos. I'm pretty sure there's more than enough information on the Internet about how to play videos in Flash.